# how to use groupby to avoid loop in python

Tags: python, loops, pandas

There are several columns in the data, three are named "candidate_id", "enddate", "TitleLevel".

Within the same id, if the enddate is the same, I will delete the lower level record.

For example, given:

```
candidate_id   startdate     enddate   TitleLevel
    1          2012.1.1      2013.5.1     2
    1          2011.1.1      2013.5.1     4
    1          2008.12.1     2010.1.1     3
    2          2010.10.1     2012.12.1    2
```

What I want is:

```
candidate_id   startdate     enddate   TitleLevel
    1          2011.1.1      2013.5.1     4
    1          2008.12.1     2010.1.1     3
    2          2010.10.1     2012.12.1    2
```

*I will delete `candidate_id=1`, `enddate=2013.5.1`, and `titlelevel=2`.*

I have come up with a loop.

```
for i in range(nrow-2,-1, -1):
    if (JobData['enddate'][i] == JobData['enddate'][i+1] 
           and JobData['candidate_id'][i] == JobData['candidate_id'][i+1] 
           and pd.notnull(JobData['enddate'][i]):
        if JobData['TitleLevel'][i] > JobData['TitleLevel'][i+1]:
            JobData= JobData.drop(i+1)
        else:
            JobData= JobData.drop(i)
```

The loop really takes some time to delete redundant rows. Is there a faster method?

Comment: If you can give some test data in the code, it will be easier for you to answer your question. Having said that, groupby is very to use. Just remember to sort the list of data before passing it to the function

Comment: It's not just pandas. I'm just trying to find a way to speed up the code, without using for loop and if else.
The test data is below "saying". In candidate_id=1, and enddate=2013.5.1, I want to delete the row which TitleLevel is lower.

Comment: @user3013706, true, but labeling with `pandas` is very helpful, because folks familiar with it will see your question

Comment: @user3013706 as you use pandas, one can give you advise basing on pandas api, not only using general python builtins

Comment: The purpose of the code is to build a statistical model. So I read in csv file using pandas. OK, I will put "pandas" in the label :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you data structure is exactly as you describe, you can use `groupby`/`max`:

```
>>> df
   candidate_id    enddate  TitleLevel
0             1   2013.5.1           2
1             1   2013.5.1           4
2             1   2010.1.1           3
3             2  2012.12.1           2
>>> df.groupby(['candidate_id','enddate']).max().reset_index()
   candidate_id    enddate  TitleLevel
0             1   2010.1.1           3
1             1   2013.5.1           4
2             2  2012.12.1           2
```

Here groupby groups rows with equal `candidate_id` and `enddate`, and `max()` evaluates maximum `TitleLevel` within each group. Result is the same as if rows with all other values being dropped.

In case you have more columns,

```
>>> df
   candidate_id    enddate  TitleLevel other_column
0             1   2013.5.1           2          foo
1             1   2013.5.1           4          bar
2             1   2010.1.1           3       foobar
3             2  2012.12.1           2       barfoo
```

you can get idexes of rows with max values, without sorting if rows order has to be preserved:

```
>>> idx = df.groupby(['candidate_id','enddate'], sort=False)['TitleLevel'].agg(lambda x: x.idxmax())
```

and filter needed rows with `ix`:

```
>>> df.ix[idx]
   candidate_id    enddate  TitleLevel other_column
1             1   2013.5.1           4          bar
2             1   2010.1.1           3       foobar
3             2  2012.12.1           2       barfoo
```

Comment: But if I still want to keep the original order of "enddate". Your code seems sorts the enddate within candidate_id. And also there are some other columns, i just extract these for example..

Comment: @user3013706 you can use sort=False param, and ix/idxmax instead of max. see updated code

Comment: In my case, i think 
groupby(['candidate_id','enddate'],sort=False)['TitleLevel'].agg(lambda x:x.max())
is right, bc it doesn't need to max its index. However, after using the code, other columns(except candidate_id, enddate, TitleLevel) are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that data is sorted by startdate (at least within each group), you can use [groupby last](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups):

```
In [11]: df.groupby(['candidate_id', 'enddate'], as_index=False).last()
Out[11]: 
   candidate_id    enddate  startdate  TitleLevel
0             1   2010.1.1  2008.12.1           3
1             1   2013.5.1   2011.1.1           4
2             2  2012.12.1  2010.10.1           2
```

Comment: Sort takes time, so I didn't sort the data by startdate. What I want to do is keeping the data with highest TitleLevel in the same candidate_id and same enddate. Do you have any ideas to do that but without sorting startdate? Thank you!